# SOAP Request in VBA Error: 'XML request is malformed'

Tags: vba, api, ms-access, soap

I am getting an error saying "XML request is malformed", and I do not know what is causing this error. I have attached below what my request body looks like, as well as what it is suppose to look like. Could you look and see if you can tell what is causing me to get this error.

This is how my request body is formatted right now:

```
sEnv = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""     xmlns:v2=""http://purolator.com/pws/datatypes/v2"">"
sEnv = sEnv & "<soapenv:Header>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:RequestContext>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Version>2.1</v2:Version>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Language>en</v2:Language>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:GroupID>111</v2:GroupID>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:RequestReference>UserRef</v2:RequestReference>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</v2:RequestContext>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</soapenv:Header>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<soapenv:Body>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:CreateShipmentRequest>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Shipment>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:SenderInformation>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Address>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Name>John Doe</v2:Name>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Company>COMPANY_NAME</v2:Company>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:StreetNumber>8</v2:StreetNumber>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:StreetName>Rainer Court</v2:StreetName>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:City>Kingston</v2:City>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Province>ON</v2:Province>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Country>CA</v2:Country>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:PostalCode>K7E4T6</v2:PostalCode>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:PhoneNumber>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:CountryCode>1</v2:CountryCode>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:AreaCode>905</v2:AreaCode>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Phone>1234567</v2:Phone>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</v2:PhoneNumber>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</v2:Address>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</v2:SenderInformation>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:ReceiverInformation>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Address>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Name>Jane Doe</v2:Name>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Company>COMPANY_NAME</v2:Company>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:StreetNumber>1234</v2:StreetNumber>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:StreetName>Douglas Road</v2:StreetName>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:City>Burnaby</v2:City>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Province>BC</v2:Province>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Country>CA</v2:Country>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:PostalCode>V5C5A9</v2:PostalCode>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:PhoneNumber>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:CountryCode>1</v2:CountryCode>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:AreaCode>604</v2:AreaCode>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Phone>2982181</v2:Phone>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</v2:PhoneNumber>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</v2:Address>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</v2:ReceiverInformation>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:ShipmentDate>2023-06-09</v2:ShipmentDate>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:PackageInformation>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:ServiceID>PurolatorExpress</v2:ServiceID>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:TotalWeight>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Value>15</v2:Value>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:WeightUnit>lb</v2:WeightUnit>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</v2:TotalWeight>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:TotalPieces>2</v2:TotalPieces>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:PiecesInformation>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Piece>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Weight>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Value>10</v2:Value>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:WeightUnit>lb</v2:WeightUnit>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</v2:Weight>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Length>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Value>5</v2:Value>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:LengthUnit>in</v2:LengthUnit>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</v2:Length>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Width>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Value>5</v2:Value>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:WidthUnit>in</v2:WidthUnit>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</v2:Width>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Height>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Value>5</v2:Value>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:HeightUnit>in</v2:HeightUnit>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</v2:Height>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</v2:Piece>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</v2:PiecesInformation>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</v2:PackageInformation>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:PaymentInformation>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:PaymentType>Sender</v2:PaymentType>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:RegisteredAccountNumber>9999999999</v2:RegisteredAccountNumber>" 
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:BillingAccountNumber>9999999999</v2:BillingAccountNumber>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</v2:PaymentInformation>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:PickupInformation>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:PickupType>DropOff</v2:PickupType>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</v2:PickupInformation>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:TrackingReferenceInformation>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:Reference1>Reference For Shipment</v2:Reference1>" 
sEnv = sEnv & "</v2:TrackingReferenceInformation>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</v2:Shipment>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:PrinterType>Thermal</v2:PrinterType>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</v2:CreateShipmentRequest>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</soapenv:Body>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</soapenv:Envelope>"
```

This is what the request body should look like once it is sent:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v2="http://purolator.com/pws/datatypes/v2"> 
    <soapenv:Header>
        <v2:RequestContext>
            <v2:Version>2.1</v2:Version>
            <v2:Language>en</v2:Language>
            <v2:GroupID>111</v2:GroupID>
            <v2:RequestReference>UserRef</v2:RequestReference>
       </v2:RequestContext>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
      <v2:CreateShipmentRequest>
          <v2:Shipment>
              <v2:SenderInformation>
                  <v2:Address>
                      <v2:Name>Test Company</v2:Name>
                      <v2:Company>Mike McGill</v2:Company>
                      <v2:StreetNumber>1075</v2:StreetNumber>
                      <v2:StreetName>Squires Beach Road</v2:StreetName>
                      <v2:City>Pickering</v2:City>
                      <v2:Province>ON</v2:Province>
                      <v2:Country>CA</v2:Country>
                      <v2:PostalCode>L1W3S3</v2:PostalCode>
                      <v2:PhoneNumber>
                          <v2:CountryCode>1</v2:CountryCode>
                          <v2:AreaCode>905</v2:AreaCode>
                          <v2:Phone>7859425</v2:Phone>
                      </v2:PhoneNumber>
                  </v2:Address>
              </v2:SenderInformation>
              <v2:ReceiverInformation>
                  <v2:Address>
                      <v2:Name>Receiver Name</v2:Name>
                      <v2:Company>Receiver Company</v2:Company>
                      <v2:StreetNumber></v2:StreetNumber>
                      <v2:StreetName>#8 Cove Road, Rural Route Ship Cove</v2:StreetName>
                      <v2:City>Pickering</v2:City>
                      <v2:Province>ON</v2:Province>
                      <v2:Country>CA</v2:Country>
                      <v2:PostalCode>L1W3S3</v2:PostalCode>
                      <v2:PhoneNumber>
                          <v2:CountryCode>1</v2:CountryCode>
                          <v2:AreaCode>905</v2:AreaCode>
                          <v2:Phone>7859425</v2:Phone>
                      </v2:PhoneNumber>
                  </v2:Address>
              </v2:ReceiverInformation>
              <v2:PackageInformation>
                  <v2:ServiceID>PurolatorQuickship</v2:ServiceID>
                  <v2:Description>Test Description</v2:Description>
                  <v2:TotalWeight>
                      <v2:Value>9</v2:Value>
                      <v2:WeightUnit>lb</v2:WeightUnit>
                  </v2:TotalWeight>
                  <v2:TotalPieces>1</v2:TotalPieces>
                  <v2:PiecesInformation>
                      <v2:Piece>
                           <v2:Weight>
                               <v2:Value>3</v2:Value>
                               <v2:WeightUnit>lb</v2:WeightUnit>
                           </v2:Weight>
                           <v2:Length>
                               <v2:Value>0</v2:Value>
                               <v2:DimensionUnit>in</v2:DimensionUnit>
                           </v2:Length>
                           <v2:Width>
                               <v2:Value>0</v2:Value>
                               <v2:DimensionUnit>in</v2:DimensionUnit>
                           </v2:Width>
                           <v2:Height>
                               <v2:Value>0</v2:Value>
                               <v2:DimensionUnit>in</v2:DimensionUnit>
                           </v2:Height>
                       </v2:Piece>
                   </v2:PiecesInformation>
        <v2:DangerousGoodsDeclarationDocumentIndicator>false</v2:DangerousGoodsDeclarationDocumentIndicator>
               </v2:PackageInformation>
               <v2:PaymentInformation>
                   <v2:PaymentType>Sender</v2:PaymentType>
                   <v2:RegisteredAccountNumber>9999999999</v2:RegisteredAccountNumber>
                   <v2:BillingAccountNumber>9999999999</v2:BillingAccountNumber>
               </v2:PaymentInformation>
               <v2:PickupInformation>
                   <v2:PickupType>DropOff</v2:PickupType>
               </v2:PickupInformation>
           </v2:Shipment>
           <v2:PrinterType>Regular</v2:PrinterType>
       </v2:CreateShipmentRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Let me know if there is anything else you would like me to provide.

Thank you

Comment: I don't see how the "Optional" lines would be generated, nor the indentation.

Comment: Visual Studio says - *The v2:Value start tag on line 1 position 1592 does not match the end tag of nsi:Value Line 1 position 1605*

Comment: @user10186832 Thank you for pointing that out. I made the change yet I am still getting the same error "XML request is malformed".

Comment: `sEnv = sEnv & "<v2:/Weight>"` should be `sEnv = sEnv & "</v2:Weight>"`